# Como dar solución getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, apache-poi

Estoy intentado realizar una descarga de un archivo excel mediante un controlador utilizando Spring, pasa todo el código, se obtiene la información desde la base de datos, se crea la hoja, las columnas, etc. Pero al llegar al final tira un error, lo veo en consola y es el siguiente: `getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta`, creo que hay una clase que está en la llamada y necesita ser cerrada, el siguiente extracto de código es del método en donde se crea el excel.

```js
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + tipoReporte + ".xlsx");
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());

        response.getOutputStream().close();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        //    file.close();
        Files.deleteIfExists(new File(filename).toPath());
```

Como estoy realizando una petición mediante Ajax, en el método principal en la cuál se realiza la llamada al método en donde se crea el Excel, casi al terminar se cae, específicamente en `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();`

```js
resultado = "S, descargado con éxito";
            json.put("resultado", resultado);
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println(json);
                out.flush();
```

Si alguien sabe como dar solución al error `Failed to complete request: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta` sería de mucha ayuda para muchos.

Comment: De nuevo: pon solo código ejecutable en la pregunta, que sea HTML/CSS/JS, como _snippet_. El código que colocaste es Java, así que no aplica. Elimina además la etiqueta [javascript].

Comment: Sin conocer del tema: ¿es posible hacer `fos.getOutputStream().flush();` y `fos.getOutputStream().close();`?

Comment: @padaleiana he probado de todo pero aún no logro darle solución